# What should be the common data type across all the database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sas

Currently I am developing an application with back end MySQL but in future I need to write all my business logic to work with SAS.

So Please suggest me what common data types should I use to avoid problems in datatype mismatch across SQL based engines and SAS. For instance SAS uses only Numeric for int/double whereas SQL based engines have different datatypes for them. If I used DECIMAL for all fields in SQL will it affect the execution time for my stored procedures ?

Extra Info: My database will have millions of rows in each table.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is.  If you are accessing the data in SAS, then the SAS drivers for the databases (or the ODBC drivers) will take care of the type conversions for particular databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should look at SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), it's a bit outdated and there are newer standards (SQL:1999 for example) but AFAIK most of the RDBMS'es should be using at least subset of that.

At least these should be ok:

- CHARACTER
- CHARACTER VARYING
- BIT
- NUMERIC
- DECIMAL
- INTEGER
- SMALLINT
- FLOAT
- REAL
- DOUBLE PRECISION
- DATE
- TIME

For each datatype you have to check the memory that it allocates. This will for sure affect performance of your execution, and not just for SQL Server. For instance, JOINs are very fast if INT is used, and can be fast enough if using NUMERIC, but I wouldn't recommend it for VARCHAR (CHARACTER VARYING). In your case, if you use DECIMAL it will surely affect the performance, but the question is: will you notice that at all?

I believe that you should focus on query optimization, stick to SQL-92 as close as possible and solve eventual problems as you go.